# SQL query to LINQ expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I cannot make the following query into LINQ expression. Could you help me ?

```
 SELECT Employee_Id_FK from TimeRegistrations as tr
  JOIN Employees em ON tr.Employee_Id_FK = em.id
  JOIN Managers m  ON em.Manager_Id_FK = m.id
  WHERE m.id = 4
```

This is what I have so far :

```
var result = from t in DB.TimeRegistrations
     join Employees  in DB.TimeRegistrations on t.Employee_Id_FK equals Employees.id
     join Managers in DB.Managers on .....          ;

// Display results.
foreach (var r in result)
{
Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Comment: Do you have foreign keys in your dbs that are mapped in your context ?

Comment: I did not mapped anything..

Comment: Are you using EF or linq 2 sql or...?

Comment: You should have navigation properties: `var registrations = Db.Managers.Find(4).Employess.TimeRegistrations`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it is not going to work if Employess is collection , you have to use `SelectMany` in this case. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your db has foreign keys:

```
 var result =from t1 in DB.TimeRegistrations
     join t2 in t1.Employees 
     join t3 in t2.Managers 
     where t3.id == "4"
     select t1
```

in case it does not:

```
 var result =from t1 in DB.TimeRegistrations
     join t2 in DB.Employees on t1.Employee_Id_FK equals t2.id
     join t3 in DB.Managers on t2.id equals t3.Manager_Id_FK 
     where t3.id == "4"
     select t1
```

However shorter way will be:

```
 var result = DB.Managers.Find(4).Employees.SelectMany(e=>e.TimeRegistrations)
```

Or not that straight forward way:

```
 var result = DB.TimeRegistrations
                .Where(t=>t.Employees.Any(e=>e.Managers.Any(m=>m.id == 4)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ! The second snippet seems to be the best solution for me. But Visual studio is underlining the t3.Manager_Id_FK  part.. I dont have Manager_Id_FK property in t3..

Comment: @user2988649 that mean that you actually have your foreign keys mapped and you should use first snippet.